# MyFirstApp tutorial Android Studio 2.3 Build Errors re EXTRA_MESSAGE and textview

Tags: java, android

MyFirstApp tutorial Android Studio Issue with receiving messages within the app.

Build Errors are as follows:

> Error:(17, 60) error: cannot find symbol variable EXTRA_MESSAGE
>   Error:(20, 57) error: cannot find symbol variable textView

My code for the message receiver looks like this:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the 
       string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = 
      intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

Note:  EXTRA_MESSAGE and textview are in RED.

The sending code looks like this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, 
             DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Note: In this line in my code from above:

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
```

The first "View" has a light horizontal line through it and I get an error message something like sendMessage(View view) is depreciated.

I think the problem may relate to the

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
```

and its depreciated code message...   (?)

Links to the tutorial where the problem arises:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 2):

check this line on your MainActivity.java file, in your code is missing.

```
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what worked, but played around with it and got it working. Checked import statements, added one or two to match documentation.